# How to make a player Validation in .erb file of Ruby on Rails solution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

In my Ruby on Rails solution (Views) I made a html.erb page in which I have the following code:

```
<h1>New Game</h1>

<%= form_for @game do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :player_1 %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :player_1 %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :player_2 %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :player_2 %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit "Create Game" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

The task is to make a validation of the players inputs (not to be the same and not to leave empty field) and I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

Comment: You can add client side as well as server side validations

Comment: I don't see a reason for down vote here...Can they comment the reason for down vote as well?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Of course not. The man can not ask for a polite answer (when he is begginer in something).

Answer (score 1):

**For server side validations:**

In app/models/game.rb you need to have the following validations,

```
validates :player_1, :player_2, presence: true
validate :player_names_uniq

def player_names_uniq
  errors.add(:base, "Player names can't be equal") if (self.player_1 == self.player_2)
end
```

**For client side validations:**

I'm not aware of how to perform the equality validation at client side.

```
<h1>New Game</h1>

<%= form_for @game do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :player_1 %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :player_1 required: true %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :player_2 %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :player_2 required: true %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit "Create Game" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```